# ImageButton icon is not showing

Tags: android, xamarin, imagebutton

I would like to have ImageButton with rounded corners and background color that is changing on pressed state. The problem is that I'm not seeing my icon at all.

This is my code:

```
<ImageButton
      android:layout_width="60dp"
      android:layout_height="60dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
      android:layout_gravity="right"
      android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
      android:background="@drawable/imgButtonStyle"
      android:src="@drawable/myIcon"
      android:id="@+id/imgButton"/>
```

Here is `imgButtonStyle.xml`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_pressed="true">
      <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:shape="rectangle">
           <solid android:color="#9F1D1F" />
           <corners android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
                    android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
                    android:topRightRadius="30dp"
                    android:topLeftRadius="30dp"/>
      </shape>
   </item>
   <item android:state_pressed="false">
      <shape 
             android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#0578AF" />
            <corners android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
                    android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
                    android:topRightRadius="30dp"
                    android:topLeftRadius="30dp"/>
      </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

Did I misunderstand something?

Any help is appreciated.

**SOLUTION**

Solution to this problem is adjusting the size of the icon to size of the ImageButton. My icon was pretty big (in comparison to size of button) so I couldn't see nothing of it.

Thank you all for your help. At the end it was a trivial problem.

Comment: post your full xml

Comment: Remove `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` from `<shape>` tag

Comment: @PriyankPatel It is not working either.

Comment: if it is not necessary to use ImageButton. you can use ImageView and wrap it inside RelativeLayout.

Comment: No error seems in your code. i think you are placing image drawable in different dpi's folder but missing a folder try putting image in drawable folder.

Answer (score 2):

**Main Activity**

```
package com.notificationdemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.demo_layout);




    }

}
```

**demo_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/temp_selector"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:id="@+id/imgButton"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**temp_selector.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#9F1D1F" />
            <corners android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
                android:topRightRadius="30dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="30dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#0578AF" />
            <corners android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
                android:topRightRadius="30dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="30dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Here i attached screen[image]

Comment: Could you be more precised? I don't understand you.

Comment: put your icon in drawable folder only and try it will work

Comment: Actually i tried your code and make a demo Project and it will work perfectly without getting any error for icon i will put ic_launcher temporary

Comment: @PeMaCN  i also attached image as well

Answer (score 0):

check this ,

**Main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgButton"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
        android:background="@drawable/imgbuttonstyle"
        android:src="@drawable/v_light" />
</LinearLayout >
```

**imgButtonStyle.xml:**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#9F1D1F" />
            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
                     android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
                     android:topLeftRadius="30dp"
                     android:topRightRadius="30dp" />
        </shape >
    </item >
    <item android:state_pressed="false" >
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#0578AF" />
            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
                     android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
                     android:topLeftRadius="30dp"
                     android:topRightRadius="30dp" />
        </shape >
    </item >
</selector >
```

Comment: As far as I can see, you changed nothing compared to my code.

Comment: i have changed nothing just added linearlayout but it is showing me button with style